# Firebird and support for batched queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, firebird, batching

Just wondering if any Firebird users can confirm that batched queries is not a supported feature in the current release (2.5) and if anyone knows if this is in the pipeline for a future version?

We use NHibernate as an ORM in our C# application and would dearly like to make use of the "Futures" feature to combine the execution of multiple queries into one request sent to the server. We've discovered that this feature isn't available as our queries "fallback" to one request per query instead of batching them.

I know Firebird has an "EXECUTE BLOCK" statement which effectively creates a virtual stored procedure but it doesn't seem possible to implement this with any of the current .NET providers for Firebird. Is anyone using Futures with Firebird? Firebird is a great database, free and can be implemented as client/server or embedded ... I mean there's not much that Firebird lacks except support for batching queries.

Any experts want to add their opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebird itself does not support query batching. This could be simulated in the driver (this is wat the Firebird JDBC driver Jaybird does), but as far as I know the .NET provider for Firebird does not provide this feature.

Firebird 4 will introduce support for batched queries in its protocol, but drivers like the Firebird ADO.net Provider and Jaybird will need to implement support for this.

Comment: Jaybird is for Java ... do you know of any .NET providers for Firebird that supports batching? Thanks for your feedback BTW, I hadn't heard of Jaybird before.

Comment: There is only one [.NET provider for Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/), the one which I assumed you are already using. As I said, as far as I know it does not support batched queries, but maybe you can get a better answer at the support list for the Firebird .NET provider.

Comment: Yes, we're using that provider. I shall take it up with support.